# Scrolling and snapping to inner elements using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, vertical-scrolling

I have a page involving 3 sections, for e.g. top, middle and bottom.

Each of the sections are of fixed height. Lets say in this case 600px;

Within the middle section, I have some content that exceeds the stated 600px height. For e.g. 1200px of content. Creating an overflow, an inner scroll bar in the middle section.

My question is:

How can I implement a jQuery solution that will provide the following scenario.

User scrolls down past the top section to the middle section, the main scroll then snaps/switches to the middle - inner content with the overflow with 1200px height. Once they have scrolled down to the end of the content, they leave the middle section and the scroll snaps/switches back to the end section.

Can you provide a solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can't do it with native scroll bar. Should be able to find a scrollbar plugin for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

this is probably not exactly the way you want it to work, but it does what you need in a way: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j2ubgxoe/3/)**

```
var passed=false;
$(document).scroll(function(){
    if($('body').scrollTop()>=$('#middle').offset().top && !passed){
        $('body').css('overflow','hidden');
        $('#container').css('overflow','auto');
        $('#container').attr("tabindex",-1).focus();
        $('#container').scrollTop(0);
    }
    else if($('body').scrollTop()<$('#middle').offset().top){
        passed=false;
    }
});
$('#container').scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop()+$(this).height()>=$('#long').height()){
        $(this).css('overflow','hidden');
        $('body').css('overflow','auto');
        passed=true;
    }
});
```

Comment: yeah, thats along the lines of the solution. What do you mean by not exactly? I'll try to adopt an implementation and get back to you :) thanks!

Comment: you're welcome, I Updated the answer, check it again, I fixed the back and forth problem (i.e. if the user scrolls down and then up and then down again).